# Monitoring JRuby processes using god gem

Tags: ruby, jruby, god, process-monitoring, process-monitor

Is it possible to monitor jruby program using [God](http://godrb.com/) ruby gem ? Any working example will be helpful. Here is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work.

Here is the God file `start_app.god`

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "simple"
  w.start = "jruby /path/to/my_jruby/my_jruby.rb"
  w.keepalive
end
```

Here is the logs when I run `god -c start_app.god -D`

```
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: Loading /path/to/start_app/start_app.god
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: Syslog enabled.
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: Using pid file directory: /var/run/god
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: Started on drbunix:///tmp/god.17165.sock
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: simple move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: simple moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: simple [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: simple move 'init' to 'start'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:38]  INFO: simple start: jruby /path/to/my_jruby/my_jruby.rb
I [2013-09-13 17:22:39]  INFO: simple moved 'init' to 'start'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:39]  INFO: simple move 'start' to 'up'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:39]  INFO: simple registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 16727
I [2013-09-13 17:22:39]  INFO: simple moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple [trigger] process 16727 exited {:pid=>16727, :exit_code=>256, :exit_signal=>17, :thread_group_id=>16727} (ProcessExits)
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple move 'up' to 'start'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple deregistered 'proc_exit' event for pid 16727
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple start: jruby /path/to/my_jruby/my_jruby.rb
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple move 'start' to 'up'
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 16753
I [2013-09-13 17:22:42]  INFO: simple moved 'start' to 'up'
```

Notice the statement `simple moved 'start' to 'up'` keeps on repeating itself meaning god couldn't start the my_jruby.rb script.

Anyone who knows the cause of this issue? If can't accomplish this using [God](http://godrb.com/), what are the possible alternatives?

Comment: is that long running process the jruby process I'm talking abt

Comment: @Viren what do u mean? I normally run the script as a process using `jruby my_jruby.rb &` but sometimes it keeps on crashing so I want monitor and restart it every time it crashes as God gem promises but it appears I can't run jruby with God

Comment: can show your jruby code

Comment: did you find a solution? is it possible to use god with jruby?

Comment: I have the save effect with ruby, I just copy/paste the god tutorial => http://godrb.com/
What was the problem for you guys?